# Overfull Hbox of includegraphics / makebox

Tags: geometry

I have a Logo that I want to display on the top right corner of my title page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xargs} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\graphicspath{{assets/}} 
\begin{document} 
\bibliography{Literatur}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=35mm,top=98mm,right=82mm,bottom=5mm}
\vspace*{-79mm}\hspace*{98mm}\noindent\makebox[55mm][c]{
  \includegraphics[width=55mm]{LOGO}
}
\vspace*{98mm}  
\begin{flushright}

\Huge{Title}
\end{flushright}
\restoregeometry
\end{titlepage}
\makeatother

\cite{itu}

\end{document}
```

The positioning is working fine but i always get an Overfull hbox warning. I tried removing the makebox which results in the exact same output.

redefining the geometry twice on a page does not seem to work (does not feel right anyway).

How can i move an Image out of the geometry without warning?

Comment: the box is 55mm wide and in it you have one space, an image that is 55cm wide and another space so it is always overfull by the width of two spaces, but putting a box around includegraphics does nothing useful so you can simply delete the makebox

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.